# Is there a way to deactivate the Connect to Outlook feature in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, outlook, features

The sharepoint site that I am using has the Connect to Outlook feature on and I wish to disable it, but I cant find which feature or what procedure I must follow in order to disable it.

Comment: Are you using a custom or OOB master page? I can write you some jQuery that will hide that button on any page that inherits from the MP

Comment: Thanks for the response, I managed to hide the option with css.